# Mongodb ignoring $push when updating.

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am tying to push a date/text to my user tables `userLog`

```
usersTable.update (
    { _id: userID },
    { $set: 
        { 
            activityDate : Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000),
            $push: { 
                userLog : {
                    date: Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000),
                    text: "Foo Baaaah!!"
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
).exec()
```

But all that Mongoose fires off is:

```
Mongoose: users.update({ _id: 'torben@rudgaard.com' }, { '$set': { activityDate: 1498158837 } }, {})
```

Any ideas where my $push went?

Comment: Where are you going to push? I don't see array where you are trying to do that.

Comment: each [update modifier](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#update-operators) goes into its own document.

Comment: My userLog is an array of elements.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I also tried `$addToSet` but that one is also ignored. Do I need [] brackets or?

Comment: @Veeram im not sure what you mean?  Do I need two $set sections in my update?  one for the activityDate  and one for userLog ?

Comment: You need a section each for set and push. Something like `{ $set:  { activityDate : Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)}, $push: { userLog : { date: Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000), text: "Foo Baaaah!!" }  }  }`

Comment: `$push` should be on the same level as `$set`
, they're different modifiers... `.update({$set: {...fields to update..}, $push: { ... somewhere: something ..}})`

Comment: Ahhhh!!!!! darn! didnt see that one at all.  So what do you guys suggest when adding to an array.. `$push` or `$addToSet` ?

Comment: Ahh....  $addToSet do not add the item to the given field if it already contains it, on the other hand $push will add the given object to field whether it exists or not.

Comment: ok someone write a solution so I can close the question please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments the `$push` operator has to be at the same level as `$set`. They are both [Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/), which means you specify the update expression in the following form:

```
{
   <operator1>: { <field1>: <value1>, ... },
   <operator2>: { <field2>: <value2>, ... },
   ...
}
```

So in your case the query has to look like this:

```
usersTable.update(
    { _id: userID },
    {
        $set: {
            activityDate: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
        },
        $push: {
            userLog: {
                date: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
                text: "Foo Baaaah!!"
            }
        }
    }
).exec();
```

Regarding [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) vs. [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) it totally depends on the use case. As you already mentioned `$addToSet` will not add an item to the array if it is already contained. `$push` will always add the given element whether it exists or not.